# How to make sure a parameter isn't changed during a recursive call?

Tags: c#, recursion, parameters

I have some data which I need to pass on to a recursive function. I want to make sure it isn't changed within that function. How can I do this?

Consider:

```
    static List<Person> GetPeopleWithSameNameAncestors(List<Person> people)
    {
        return people.Where(person => HasAncestorWithName(person.Parents, person.Name)).ToList();
    }

    //Here, nameToLookFor is always the same for every outside call to this function
    static bool HasAncestorWithName(List<Person> lookIn, String nameToLookFor)
    {
        return lookIn.Any(p => p.Name == nameToLookFor || (p.Parents != null && HasAncestorWithName(p.Parents, nameToLookFor)));
    }
```

Real situation is more complicated, that's why it's important to make sure nameToLookFor isn't changed, because somebody could easily do that. Oh, and I can't touch the "Person" class.

If this isn't possible directly, does anybody know a pattern which could solve this problem safely?

Comment: things you don't want changed should be wrapped in immutable classes. `string` is immutable, it won't change on you. `List<T>` is not, consider passing an `IEnumerable<T>` instead. Also, if you want `Person` to not change, consider wrapping it in a custom read-only container for `Person`, like `ReadOnlyPerson`.

Comment: Is the recursive function a delegate you don't control?

Comment: If you are passing a normal reference type you are giving the callee access to that parameter. Some types have a level of immutability, from the hard immutability of the `String` type to the softer immutability of a `readonly` interface. Alternatively you could clone your instance but this seems wasteful. If you can't "trust" the recursive function, you shouldn't call it until you've read and refactored it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really worried about this, consider using the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to wrap your Person object - but wrap it, as to make it Immutable.

```
public class PersonWrapper()
{
    Person p;

    public PersonWrapper(Person person)
    {
        prop = person;
    }

    Public string Name
    {
        get { return p.Name; }
    }
}
```

Pass this object around in your code - you can easily convert the list like:

```
var immutablePersonList = personList.Select(p => new PersonWrapper(p));
```

Also, use Immutable collection types, like IEnumerable instead of mutable ICollection implementations.